# Why does hibernate request to database return null?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, request

I have following DAO method:

```
@Override
    public Company getCompanyById(Long companyId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Company.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("companyId", companyId));
        return (Company) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

I pass 2L to this function. but gets null as return value although in database exist entry with following id.

Also in debug I tryed to evaluate following expression:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from Company")
```

result:

```
SQLQueryImpl(select * from Company):
    queryReturns = {java.util.ArrayList@7974} size = 0
    querySpaces = null
    callable = false
    autodiscovertypes = false
    queryString = {java.lang.String@7967}"select * from Company"
    session = {org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@5735}"SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[]])"
    parameterMetadata = {org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata@7975}
    values = {java.util.ArrayList@7976} size = 0
    types = {java.util.ArrayList@7977} size = 0
    namedParameters = {java.util.HashMap@7978} size = 0
    namedParameterLists = {java.util.HashMap@7979} size = 0
    optionalObject = null
    optionalId = null
    optionalEntityName = null
    selection = {org.hibernate.engine.RowSelection@7980}
    cacheable = false
    cacheRegion = null
    comment = {java.lang.String@7981}"dynamic native SQL query"
    flushMode = null
    cacheMode = null
    sessionFlushMode = null
    sessionCacheMode = null
    collectionKey = null
    readOnly = false
    resultTransformer = null
```

It looks like empty result.

try to execute it from  database:

[image]

Please help to find mistake.

Comment: Well, you're probably not querying the same database/schema. Or the data you're seeing in the postgresql SQL editor hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: @JB Nizet you are right!!!